# Variable doesn't increment

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQueryMobile, but I have a problem with the variable "jugadores". I increment the value on a click function, but when I access to it in an other page only show me the initial value, I mean 1.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jugadores = 1;          //initial value
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        var AddButton = $("#agregar");
        $(AddButton).click(function (e) {
            jugadores++;    
        });
    });
    </script>
```

and the HTML:

```
<div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Jugadores</h1>
        </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="divjug">
        <input type="text" name="fname1" id="jug1" placeholder="Jugador #1">
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn" id="agregar">Agregar jugador</a>
        <a href="#contador" class="ui-btn" id="siguiente">Siguiente</a>
    </div>
</div>


<div data-role="page" id="contador">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Contador</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write(jugadores);  //always print 1, no matter if I increment
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: JavaScript cannot maintain state. Every time the page is loaded the JavaScript is reinitialized. Use PHP or another server side language to maintain state.

Comment: @Swivelgames The OP appears to be using jQuery Mobile, which doesn't necessarily renew the entire document in the act of switching between `page`s.

Comment: I can only use javascript

Comment: Is yours javascript block being loaded in by jQuery Mobile each time you navigate? If so, that will cause the issue. Otherwise you could simply try: `jugadores = jugadores || 1` Which will prevent jugadores from being *reset* back to 1 if it already has a value.